# Could the search result please stay in the same tab if I change some search term?

Tags: feature-request, search

I recently do often search queries like [`title:problem [java] closed:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:problem%20%5Bjava%5D%20closed:0) on Stack Overflow.

These give quite a lot of results, and are in no particular order ("Relevance", whatever this means). Thus I select the ["active" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=title:problem%20%5Bjava%5D%20closed:0) to see recently active questions with these search terms (to avoid spamming the first page when editing too old questions). I click some questions (and edit the titles).

Then I think "Are there also any new questions if I change **problem** to **problems**"? So, I add an `s` to the edit box over the list, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and ...

I'm again on the ["relevance" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:problems%20%5Bjava%5D%20closed:0&submit=search) (with the new search term). So I have to click the ["active" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=title:problems%20%5Bjava%5D%20closed:0) again.

I think that I did this at least a dozen times today (with slightly differing search terms: `problem`, `question`, `help`, `problems`, `questions`, and in the tags [java](/questions/tagged/java), [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [git](/questions/tagged/git), [javac](/questions/tagged/javac), [javadoc](/questions/tagged/javadoc), [encryption](/questions/tagged/encryption), [cryptography](/questions/tagged/cryptography), ..., with and without `closed:0`).

**Could the search**, at least if invoked from this search box over the result list, **please remember on which tab I was, and show the result in the same tab** (e.g. ordered the same way)**?**

Comment: A real pain point and really annoying :( Relevance doesn't seem to be calculated in a way that is helpful to me. It usually lists old and often outdated results. Switching back to "relecance" also does happen "silently". I often wonder why the search result doesn't provide anything useful until I see that the wrong tab is activated again, even though I just changed it a second before.

Comment: I run into the same issue. Can a ["declined" request"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135067/search-doesnt-remember-the-tabs) be voted "reopen" ? My (simple) suggestion would be to allow an addtional "search-field" command to select the tab, i.e something like "@new" goes to the newest tab while "@active" goes to the active tabe etc. This way, the default may still remain

Comment: I have now posted a [related request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278130/specify-destination-tab-in-search) which would solve this as well.