# Search doesn't remember the tabs

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, search, rate-limiting

When searching a site, we have four tabs: `relevance,newest,votes,active`.

Now, the auto-focused tab is "relevance". Sometimes, I want to search via the `newest` tab. Since search sucks, this required multiple searches.

But, every time I change my search, it defaults to the `relevance` tab. Which means I have to go through an extra page load, and extra click, and I hit the rate limit pretty fast (`You can only perform 6 searches within a 60 second window, please wait a moment and try again.`).

The same applies to chat. There are the tabs `relevance,stars,newest`. IMO, `relevance` is useless. Again, I hit the rate limit and have to wait a minute since I need to keep switching tabs.

Pretty annoying.

Tabs are supposed to be..well..*tabs*. They don't change unless you want them to. That's pretty standard when it comes to tabs.

Can we please add tab memory to the search tabs?

Comment: I too find the limit annoying, though I doubt switching tabs counts towards that. Nick [wrote a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84311/please-increase-searches-per-minute#comment226659_84337): *In the next build tabs/pages will not count*. So, if it does count, that's actually a bug. (Still then, remembering the tabs is nice anyhow.)

Comment: This is something we should be able to fix pretty easily. I'll bring it up next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took this to the team, and unfortunately it's going to be a no fix.

Besides the fact that this used to be the other way and it was specifically altered to behave in the way it currently does (before I got here),  the main argument is that search result  relevance is by far the best sort...to the point that getting results by any other sort method would be confusing.

Keep in mind that we did greatly improve relevance recently when we moved to a new search engine.

Comment: True... The only time _I_ use search is when I'm looking for a meta post that I already know exists (in which case "newest" usually works best)

Comment: What about chat? AFAICT, chat search is still on the old engine (and it's still default OR).

Comment: Moving chat to a elastic search is actually on our planning board; it just keeps getting bumped for more important things. I'd like to wait till that goes out for anymore tweaks.

Comment: relevance usually lists old results. There may be topics where old results with lots of upvotes are ok, but IT has a lot of fast changing topics where 6 month old q+a are outdated. It is such a pain to have to switch the tab again every time I refine the search terms.

Comment: 3 years in and I run into the same issue. Can a "declined" request be voted "reopen" ?  My (simple) suggestion would be to allow an addtional "search-field" command to select the tab, i.e something like "@new" goes to the *newest* tab while "@active" goes to the active tabe etc. This way, the *default* may still remain...

Comment: I have now ['re-requested'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278130/specify-destination-tab-in-search) it...

Comment: What is confusing about using the other sort options? Newest clearly means chronologically. Votes is by number of votes. Surely you can't have both at the same time using Relevance. They decided to not make sort order a user preference. Shame on them for imposing their opinion on us.