# Problem with the chat search rate limiter

Tags: feature-request, chat, search, rate-limiting

At some point semi-recently chat searches became rate-limited. I tend to search for something and then immediately change the sort order to "newest". This counts as two rapid searches, and I get this error all the time:

> You can perform this action again in 1 seconds

Can chat search be changed to account for this? Allow two searches every four seconds, or don't count changing the sort order as a new search, for example

Comment: Somewhat related (since the problem for me at least is the fact that it makes me switch to begin with): [Search doesn't remember the tabs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135067)

Comment: @TimStone Oh, wow; I hadn't seen that one. That fix would be fine instead of this

Comment: I personally don't care so long as I can stop having a reason to shake my fist at the screen. Arguably the presentation of that error could use some work too, but that's not really a huge issue.