# How to make votes the default sort order for search results?

Tags: support, search

Votes used to be the default sort order for search results or at least the website remembered my choice. Ever since it changed to a dropdown with Active and Votes, I have to change it to Votes. Is there a way to make the Votes option the default one?

Comment: It looks like your choice isn't sticky for search the way it is for the questions link.  Hmm.

Comment: @MonicaCellio it never was. Tony, if you can add links and examples maybe someone can reproduce what you describe.

Comment: I search for +title:disable  [angularjs] and selected Votes. Hit enter. Hit enter again and it's back to Relevance.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich indeed. That's how it always was. Feel free to submit a feature request asking to change this behavior, but personally I like the way it is.

Comment: Actually, someone else did it before and it's declined: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135067/search-doesnt-remember-the-tabs

Answer (score 2):

No, search results are **always** sorted by relevance initially. Changing the sort of the search results was never sticky, in all my years in Stack Exchange.

Most likely you're confusing search results with tag questions list, where changing the sort is "sticky" and applied again whenever viewing any other tag. Can't reproduce what you describe in tag page as well, the sort is applied fine as it always did.

Comment: The default seems to always be 'Relevance'. The dropdown is always set to 'More'. I want it to be Votes. ALWAYS. I want the site to put my setting in the cookie and use it. I am using tags in my search. I can reproduce this issue every time. It keeps reverting to Relevance after I used Votes and this happens on the same search I just did.