# Specify destination tab in search or allow a sorting-keyword

Tags: feature-request, search

When I type in some search, I do not *always* want to end up on the "relevance" tab. Use-case:

> I use the search to 'filter' for newly active questions by using the search field
>   `is:question -[foo]`
>   so that I see what is currenlty active, but *not* tagged with [foo](/questions/tagged/foo). (Everything else but [foo](/questions/tagged/foo))
>
> I do then want to end up on either the *active* or the *newest* tab, but not on the *relevance* tab.

From a quick search, this seems to be like that [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135067/search-doesnt-remember-the-tabs) ( [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) ), but I would like to suggest a slightly alternative request, which might keep best of both worlds:

**Can the search box get some addtional 'command' flag keyword to specifiy the destination tab?**

Essentially, I would suggest that entering `is:q -[foo]` works as of now, but that entering `is:q -[foo] @newest` would open the *newest* tab instead. And similar for keywords `@votes` and `@active`.

I don't care if `@` is the best keyword, maybe not, any syntax would do...

---

**Edit**

More than a year later and not a single answer or comment. Am I missing something? I was searching for the same thing today and still can't find the relevant information. Why *not* have an addtional *advanced search* option for the sorting/tab?